# What are the available image sliders?

Tags: 7, media, javascript

I want to know what sliders are available for Drupal 7, and which ones can be used in blocks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See handbook page [Comparison of Rotator / Slider modules](http://drupal.org/node/418616).

[image: screenshot]