# Embedding the s3slider jQuery plugin in a block

Tags: 7, blocks, media, javascript

How can I add a custom image slider similar to [this one](http://www.serie3.info/s3slider/demonstration.html) in a block?
I tried integrating it in a block, but it doesn't work.

What is the best image slider for Drupal 7, excluding the [View Slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) module? I tried using it, but it only displays the last image of the slideshow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use in D7 the [Fields Slidesho](http://drupal.org/project/field_slideshow)w module.

If you still want to use the s3 slider, these are some general steps to make.

1. Make a content type with an imagefield.
2. Add nodes for each slide in your slider.
3. Create a view that has the fields you need.
4. Set the field stye of the imagefield to none for all the items (label and wrapper too).
5. Set the body field style to span and set none to label and wrapper. Trim the field to your desired length and remove any html.
6. Go to 'Theme information' in your view. You need to copy the name of the templates of the views you will be replacing. You need to get the list template (views-view-list--MYVIEWNAME.tpl.php).
7. Go to the themes folder in the views module and copy the views-view-list.tpl.php into your theme and rename it to what you figured out in the first step.
8. Change the content of the template with something like this, remember to change MYTHEMENAME to the name of your theme and remember to flush your theme registry so it recognizes the new template file.

   - I couldn't add the code successfully so I made a Drupalbin: http://drupalbin.com/20119

Comment: This technique could also be followed with a single node using an multi imagefield and theming it in the node template.

Comment: where should i put the code provided at given link, could not understand with step 5 - how to access Theme information in view. whats with step 7 and 8.

Comment: Go to the 'advanced' fieldset in your view (while editing your view display, on the right hand side) and search for the 'theme information' link, its towards the end. You will see a dialog box come up with your needed information. As towards the code, just replace views-view-list.tpl.php with the code linked.

Comment: Its easy to have a jQuery slider in Drupal using one of the contributed modules, but for something so specific like using the s3 slider, you need a good understanding of views and theming. However if you follow the steps correctly you should be able to make it, if not go on irc and you can ask for help there too: http://drupal.org/irc

Comment: Where you able to integrate the plugin? If my mini tutorial was useful please accept the answer as the correct one by hovering over the up/down vote widget and clicking the check icon.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you tried that, there are many ways to achieve it in Drupal. Often they are displayed in blocks. See this question [What are the available image sliders?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2944/what-are-the-available-image-sliders/2965#2965). Links referred there could take you to various slideshow modules available for Drupal but in my experience it is always more than installing and configuring modules.